# Is it possible to buy a German prepaid SIM Card from outside Germany?

Tags: germany, cellphones

I live in Spain but I will be travelling to Germany in a few months (February 2016) and I'd like to buy a prepaid SIM card to have internet on my phone while I'm there.

I've been to Germany before and I know that I can buy a SIM card in almost any major supermarket. At the moment I don't have any German card, but I would like to get one before arriving there to be able to use the internet as soon as I get off the plane.

Last time I used an [Aldi Talk](https://www.alditalk.de/) SIM card and I thought that it might be possible to get one sent to Spain, but the page just lets you send it to a German destination.

**Is there any company that sends German SIM cards to other countries (specifically Spain)? Is it possible to buy a prepaid SIM card from outside Germany?**

I am interested just in internet access, voice calls and text messages are not important for me when considering a SIM card.

Answer (score 8):

Try searching in [Amazon Germany](http://www.amazon.de) "prepaid simkarte". [This](http://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B0081G32LE/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new) is just an example from the search result. Some sellers provide information regarding delivery fee (click on Internationale und Inlandsversandkosten). For example, the first seller charges 1.50€ to send the SIM card to Spain.

Answer (score 3):

At least one company is shipping outside Germany: http://www.travel-sim-germany.com

Comment: It's also good to mention if you're in any way affiliated with them

Comment: dead link. it is now a whiskey site

Answer (score 1):

i used a lebara sim card in germany and the internet works really good.
maybe this will be a opportunity for you.
I found the card here [beachsim](http://www.beachsim.com/product/germany-prepaid-sim-card-pay-as-you-go/?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

On eBay Germany there are many sellers of German SIM cards with shipping abroad, just check this category: http://www.ebay.de/sch/SIM-Karten-/29778/i.html

P.S. I actually had a German ALDI Talk SIM card, and then after not using it at all for 21 months (not even being in Germany, and not putting the SIM card in the phone), I was back in Germany and found out the SIM card still worked (although it had zero balance). I just recharged 15 EUR from a train station machine, and was good to go, so you might check your old SIM card, maybe it also still works.

Actually ALDI Talk is pretty good value if you use a lot of data, as you can get 1 GB each day for 2 EUR daily fee, and I found out that I use about half a GB on an average day. The only downside is that it only has good data in big cities (it had LTE in Berlin), and just outside the city it was only GPRS/EDGE, very poor speed, so if you plan to use it outside the cities, you might want to buy a Vodafone SIM card for example.

Comment: The provider ALDI Talk is using has recently merged with O2, so coverage should be much better now, although they are still working on some aspects of the integration. UMTS will be completed by mid January, LTE will take until summer.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017 you no longer need to buy a German SIM card, as all roaming fees have been abolished within the EU. Therefore you can use your regular Spanish tariff and not worry about any extra fees.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of some rule changes when it comes to registration and activation of SIM cards as of July 2017. Some providers have chosen not to sell prepaid SIM cards anymore as they did not want to deal with the paperwork required.